# Return all rows from an array

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to return a comma separated list of location names from a database.

So far I have the SQL statement that I know works because it returns the correct results when tested in phpMyAdmin.

I'm now trying to get the results returned and printed on screen in php.

The code I have bellow only seems to return the first result.

```
 $sql = "SELECT user_locations.location_id, location.name AS LocName FROM user_locations INNER JOIN location ON user_locations.location_id=location.id WHERE user_id = '" . $id . "'";
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row['LocName'];
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
    return $comma_separated;
 }
```

Comment: that might be because you `return` directly after the first row - your while loop never gets a chance to finish

Comment: You have to initialize the Array outside the loop, add every row inside and implode outside again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to remove the `implode` and `return` outside your `while` loop, otherwise your loop will stop after the first value:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_locations.location_id, location.name AS LocName 
        FROM user_locations 
        INNER JOIN location ON user_locations.location_id=location.id 
        WHERE user_id = '" . $id . "'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row['LocName'];
}  
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
return $comma_separated;
```

Note that you can achieve this result directly in your query using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(location.name) AS LocName
        FROM user_locations 
        INNER JOIN location ON user_locations.location_id=location.id
        WHERE user_id = '" . $id . "'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$comma_separated = $row['LocName'];
return $comma_separated;
```

Note that dependent on the source of your `$id` value, you may need to look into [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Comment: @JackCrozz Please note my edit which shows how to get a comma separated list directly from the database without looping in the PHP code.

Comment: Thank You! The second way is better I think. Also adding in SEPARATOR ', ' to the group_concat because the default is a , with no spaces either side.

Comment: @JackCrozz The second way is definitely easier. I didn't add the separator because in your original code you just had a comma with no spaces.